# Three part dynamic spacing wo/Table and Absolute Positioning

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm trying to place 3 divs within a larger div such that the center one is 800px wide, and centered, and the other two fill the space remaining. I cannot use tables, nor can I use absolute positioning, as I have html below that must be outside the three divs but inside the larger div. I can get the center div:

```
.center-div {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

But how do I position the other two divs?

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="left-div"></div>
    <div id="center-div"></div>
    <div id="right-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your html markup, atleast a sample of it. and the containing larger div, is that 100% of the viewport?

Comment: The side divs can be floated to the left and right, but if the outer div can be of any width, I don't see offhand how this is possible without using Javascript to get the width and set the widths of the side divs accordingly.  

Are you looking for the bottoms of the divs to line up as well?

Comment: The containing larger div is 100% of the viewport.

Comment: Unless you want to start messing with javascript you will have a hard time mixing % widths and fixed widths. What happens when the browser window is less than 800px?

Comment: I'm not too worried about, given my end user spectrum, but I would say that the sidebars would just be empty, and the center would have a horizontal scrollbar (part of the window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* try messing around with `display: table-row;` for the container `div` and `display: table-cell;` for the inner `div`s.  You might even need a second container with `display: table;`—the basic idea is emulating a table without using `table`, `tr`, and `td`.

All those `table-`values for the `display` property are [specified in CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display), but I have never personally tested which browsers support them.  I’ll bet my money though that IE6 won’t be able to cope with it. ;-)

Comment: I guess I'd prefer not to use tables or anything equivalent.

Comment: You wouldn’t *use* a table, but rather *emulate the behavior* of a table.

Comment: No, it is not.  It is a pure CSS approach.  If it were equivalent, then styling text with `style='color: red;'` and using `<font color='red'>` would also qualify as ‘equivalent’.